# Anycubic Chiron does not print correctly

Tags: print-quality

I recently got my Anycubic Chiron.

First I was very exited and set up the printer. I started the first manual leveling as described in the instuctions. After that I did the Autoleveling and started the test print - so far so good.

After adjusting by 2 mm, further down I saw the round circle in the middle is not round and it seems that in some areas the printer does not position the nozzle correctly. As I printed a cylinder I saw the circle has two flat areas opposing each other when the build plate moves towards its end position.

Does anybody now how to fix this? Is there anybody with a Cura 4.0 Machine setting and a 0.05 mm with 0.4 mm nozzle profile?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, and welcome to 3D Printing.SE! I would recommend that in addition to reading some highly voted questions to gauge the standard expected, that you take a look at the [help] section relating to asking questions, in particular [ask], and take the [tour] for more information on how stack exchange works. Thanks :-) E.g. this question might be closed as unclear what you ask and would benefit a lot from correct punctuation and addition of photos to support your text. Please update your question by [edit]. We all love to help out!

Comment: A photo or diagram would be a very helpful addition to the question.

Comment: Thanks I will take a Pic and post it. I check the belt and it seems that they are a bit loose I will correct this and try again.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to give a definitive answer without photographic evidence, since your description of the problem does not give enough information. The most common causes of "circular objects not printing correctly" are loose belts and loose grub screws on the belt drive pulleys.

However, you should note that the printer's firmware will not allow the print head to be moved outside the defined maximum printing area under software (g-code) control. This will cause large objects to be truncated if they extend outside of the defined maximum printing area, and I suspect that this is what is happening.

Comment: Cura denies to slice objects that are in any part out of bounds.